# Ajax post vars not seen in PHP script

Tags: php, ajax, post

I am trying to initiate an ajax post call to a php script where it will update some values in my database.

The problem I have is, the POST values are not seen in my php script, or at least I have no response.

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("btnOpsb" ).onclick = pinOpsb;
function pinOpsb(){
var params = "wxdata = test";
var ajaxRequest;
try{ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();} catch (e){try{ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");} catch (e) {try{ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");} catch (e){alert("Error: Browser/Settings conflict");return false;}}}
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("POST","wx2strip.php",true);
    ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajaxRequest.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
}
</script>
```

In my wx2strip.php I have tried echo back something if $_POST had anything in it, but even when I just echo something at the top of the script and exit, there is still no response in the alert I created.

I tried using get, and I do get a response back.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these two lines to set the right headers:

```
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", "fname=Henry&lname=Ford".length);
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

Content-length is required for POST.

Comment: Thanks for that, it did solve it. I was not aware that the length is required, great to know!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that [Aerik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10628221/259014) is correct about why you are experiencing problems.

That said, since you are already using jQuery in your javascript, I believe you will simplify things quite a bit if you look into using [jQuery's `$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). It will handle all of these types of complications for you, so if there are any other small issues like that, you won't run into problems.

Comment: I will definitely look into using JQ at a latter time. I just love to learn the core language first before I use any libraries like JQuery so I can get a good understanding.